# How to perform jquery ajax delete operation when delete is to remove an entry in mongodb?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

I have a sample nodejs app with api in mondodb connected via mongoose. I get a bunch of responses something like this (Sinple Entry below)

```
    {
    name:"Task1"
    status:["pending"]
    0:"pending"
    __v:0
    _id:"592d6a398eb24a9ac85d1184"
   }
```

Now If I have to delete the entry I will create a route like:

```
/tasks/_id
```

which I have created in nodejs and it works fine. I need perform a delete operation using an ajax delete operation. How do I create a route like /tasks/_id in ajax that will delete the record. Below is my code.

```
     $.ajax({
      type:'DELETE',
      url:'/tasks/' + how to get _id here from mongodb, which could be available only on successful ajax operation,

        success : function( data) {
          console.log('success);
       },
      error : function() {
        console.log('error');

      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

First in ajax the property name is 'method' not 'type'. secondly you for delete a record you should have mongodb record id in link or somewhere
like /tasks/mongodbId or /tasks/343sddfsdf3434 in frontend. you can display or print via some loop etc.
or assume var id = task._id;

```
<a id="link" data-mongo-id="sfsdfs4343dsfds" href="tasks/sfsdfs4343dsfds">link<a/>
```

then you can call ajax method from frontend.

```
$.ajax({
      method:'DELETE',
      url:'/tasks/' + $("#link").attr('data-mongo-id'),

        success : function( data) {
          console.log('success);
       },
      error : function() {
        console.log('error');

      }
    })
```

At backend you can use method like

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.delete('tasks/:mongo_id', function (req, res) {
 ///your mongose delete query

Task.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.mongo_id, function (err, task) {  

var response = {
    message: "task successfully deleted",
    id: req.mongo_id
};
    res.send(response);
   });

    })
```